# review audit, what counts as low quality

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

I encountered the following as a review audit

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25337360

The answer certainly tries to answer the question, it may be wrong or not but I was under the impression that technical correctness was not sufficient for a post to enter the low quality queue.

Am I missing something? It does not seem worthy of a review ban

Comment: People with less than 10k reputation can't see the deleted answer; can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: If you click the *link* link you'll see the post was deleted. It was deleted as **spam** - that link the answer contains points to a personal blog. No idea whether the this person has overdone linking to their blog, but the fact that the answer had been deleted would inform you that you're dealing with an audit and the "Looks OK" would be the wrong action...

Comment: That post looks ok to me by itself - so "skip" would be better option if you can't vouch for technical correctness (I can't)... I doubt you would get *manual ban* for that (indeed you can get automatic ban, but you need more failed reviews for that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "That post looks ok to me by itself" ... the affiliation disclosure is missing.

Comment: Imho, we are starting to go a bit too far in what we expect reviewers to note in the LQP queue. One would have to check the impressum of the linked page to find out that this page is from op. If we check each and every possible situation, we don't get any reviews done anymore.

Comment: @Tom my point is that post looks way out of place (for me) in LQP queue. Since I have zero technical expertise in that particular subject I would skip the post. The fact this post has a link to somewhere would not impact my decision to skip it. Now if I do decide to look at the post indeed I'd look at the link, but looking at it is *very unlikely* I would have found direct link between author of the answer and blog (nor get concerned enough to dive in to investigate other posts by the same author) and hence likely to fail this audit too.

Comment: @BDL Or just look at the profile, but if you prefer to check the impressum ...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't ment to say you couldn't/shouldn't skip, that's a fine option of course.